# ExhaustiveTemplateMatching with transparency?

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I am trying to use `ExhaustiveTemplateMatching` from `AForge` with transparency support. However, it only allows bitmaps to be in grayscale or RGB 24 BPP.

This is an issue, since it considers transparent pixels of my template.

I want it to ignore the parts of my template that are transparent.

How can I do this?

This is how I do the comparison today.

```
var templateMatching = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(0.8f);
var matchings = templateMatching.ProcessImage(sourceImage, templateImage);
```